# Android 4.1: how to enable ADB over internet on device with pared-down menu?

Tags: android, adb

I have a problem with Fly IQ449. It haven't got full developer menu. Also, I can't connect it via USB (I tried to install different drivers, but ADB still doesn't work). And I haven't got root.
7x tapping on "build number" in device info menu doesn't work too. Absolutely no effect.
Is it possible to do it?

/sorry for my google english/

Answer (score 0):

for adb to work , you need to explicitly enable it via Developer Settings. If such an option is not available in your Phone , try to have a custom ROM like Cynogenmod Installed and you will get the options there .

Comment: adb-over-usb is enabled, but it isn't work. adb-over-internet is not available.

Comment: get a copy of adb to your system . You can get it by downloading the SDK for Android and look in the platform tools section.